# Does the introduction of authentication justify a major-version bump according to Semantic-Versioning?

Tags: authentication, semantic-versioning

semver.org states:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH,
>
> increment the [..] MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes

I have a Maven-Plugin, that gathers some data and sends it (via REST) to a server component.
Unsecured until now.

So, if I don't change the API iself, but introduce changes, that would render an older version of the Maven-Plugin useless without the newly added process and configuration, shouldn't I increment the MAJOR version?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you've have or are anticipating a breaking change on the server. You have consider what ever it is you are versioning here.  It sounds like you are versioning both components with the same version string, is that correct?

Comment: @jwdonahue yes, both backend and client are released with the same version.